# Meaning difference caused by intonation

Tags: intonation

I’m English learner living in Korea and I’ve just studied English ‘intonation.’ I already know when people speak a general sentence, the last word is focused.

However, I can’t understand some parts of the book.

“If people want to emphasize on the words in the sentence, they can put an intonation on the sentence. For instance,

(General sentence) There is a lot of books on the table.

1. (emphasis on ‘lot’)There is a **lot** of books on the **table**
2. (emphasis on ‘lot’)There is a **lot** of books on the table.”

Is there any meaning difference between the sentence 1 and 2?

Does Sentence 2 emphasize on the word ‘lot’ more than Sentence 1?

Comment: Intonation is about the rise and fall in pitch, not about the emphasis or stress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning, but there is a difference in emphasis.

Sentence 1 stresses both the quantity of books and the location.

Sentence 2 stress just the quantity.

Which words a speaker would emphasise would depend on the context.

If the speaker wants to emphasise both the number of books and their location, the emphasis is per 1.

If it's just the quantity that's important, sentence 2.

Both are possible. The choice depends on the speaker's intention.

Answer (score 0):

Intonation is the rise and fall in pitch in a phrase.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/intonation

It is quite complex, but one example where intonation can make a difference is using rising intonation on a statement to turn it into a question, or a statement of disbelief.

> You're married.

With falling intonation is a statement of fact, and an odd thing to state, since person you are talking to probably knows if they are married or not.

> You're married?

With rising intonation means  "Wow I'm surprised that you are married! Is it really true?  Tell me more."

Don't confuse intonation with stress.  We don't mark intonation with bold, but it is often implied by punctuation. Too little intonation makes you sound like a robot. But too much makes you sound a little crazy.  The best way to learn how much is right is to listen to a lot of English.

There are also dialect differences: notably Australian English which tends to use rising intonation a lot.